# Solution structure using LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

My basic ASP.NET structure is always 3 projects

- DAL = Data accesses layer - dealing with the db
- Bussiness logic layer - dealing with all action and functions
- Presentation layer - Present data to website

Do i need to change my basic structure because i want to develop with LINQ to sql?

What is the best structure to develop with LINQ to sql?

Comment: Do you mean LINQ itself, or LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities?

Comment: do you mean `LinQToSQL`?

Comment: I woudn't use linq to sql for new projects. As it's not anymore Microsoft-Strategic.

Comment: LINQ to SQL and EF are particularly well-suited for this structure because the `IQueryable<T>` chain is easily maintained [all the way to the UI](http://ayende.com/blog/3958/the-dal-should-go-all-the-way-to-ui).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The structure, can remain the same. But I would use Entity Framework instead, that's what Microsoft is pushing in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL is a very simple ORM, a thin layer on top of your database.
So if you decided to use it in your project, treat it as the DAL.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to change the structure of you projects. Your DAL basically becomes a place for your LinqToSql models, classes etc.
Like other suggested, you should consider Entity Framework (LinqToEntities) instead of the no-longer-in-development LinqToSql.
You can read on Entity Framework [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For new projects, I'd start with this structure and adapt to requirements as necessary:

- C# POCO Domain Objects (a.k.a. "business" objects)
- Entity Framework 4.1 Code First
- WCF Web Services
- ASP .NET MVC 3 using Razor, or WebForms if you have some very compelling reason to do so

Your web applications should connect to the WCF services for data access.

Comment: I would not use WCF if not really needed, because it's quiet more complex.

Comment: @gsharp: It used to be considerably more difficult to set up, but with recent versions that's really not the case. In my experience most projects end up needing WCF at some point so I recommend planning for it up front. As I said though - adapt this outline to your specific requirements.

Comment: Did you had any experience creating this structure using entity framework 5? i can't separate the C# POCO Domain object from the location where the Entity framework exist...

Answer (score 0):

Use POCOs.

If you're really set on using LINQ to Sql, use it to populate POCOs. Heck, use whatever you want, but send them back to your Business Logic and UI as a POCO.  As mentioned before, L2S is not 'blessed' by microsoft anymore, which is the beauty of using POCOs. Let's face it, it's only a matter of time before EF isn't 'blessed' and the next big thing comes along.

If you use POCOs, the only thing you need to change is your DAL and how you get data to create your POCOs. Everything else will remain unchanged.